# Windows installer can't format SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, diskpart

Laptop: Asus Rog G750jm. The laptop suddenly started to get into a bootloop every time i started it. I tried reinstalling Windows 10 by creating a Bootable disk on a Mac and it fails to format the primary partition every single time. Error: 0x80070057 comes up every single time. I have tried deleting all the partitions and then recreating then through the windows install setup and I also tried format fs=ntfs by going into diskpart through the Bootable USB, nothing works. It gets stuck at 0% when done through diskpart for more than 10-15 minutes. I tried checking ssd's "health" via wmic and then diskdrive get status, I got ok ok. So I'm not sure what is going on here. Portions can be deleted and recreated but it won't format and or install Windows on it. Any help is appreciated.

Also, the windows 10 installer detects the ssd but it won't show up under Boot in bios, but it is displayed in the Sata Configuration option under Advanced tab in bios.

Comment: Does your SSD require drivers?  During the Windows installation there will be a screen where you choose which partition to install to.  On that same screen is a button to load manufacturer drivers.  Some drives will not function properly unless those drivers are loaded.

Comment: I didn't load any drivers the first time I installed it, but I'll download them and put them on the same USB drive and see if that helps. So I just do Load drivers and let it do its thing and try installing windows again?

Comment: The Sata Mode Selection  us AHCI, is that what it's supposed to be?

Comment: Windows 10 should come with generic AHCI drivers but do try your manufacturer drivers just to see if it works.

Comment: I have the Samsung 850 Evo 500Gb but I can't find a firmware or a driver for it. All Samsung has is a Magician utility but it's an exe, it would only run as a Windows program but it isn't the driver.